# How to select from a table using row of another table and update

Tags: oracle

I have a sourcetable in the format..

```
                id col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
                 1 Peter DEM  Scott Neo  Morpheus.
```

A index table in the format

```
                 id D T fromfieldsource tofieldmaster
                  1 123               col1               col4      A
                  1 123               col1               col5      B
```

I have a mastertable in the format :-

My job is to update:=

```
                           id  A    B          C    D 

                              NEO  MORPHEUS
```

Final Output
Can anyone help me..I am a newbie in Oracle and Toad.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is difficult to read; please, format text. You said that there's a "sourcetable", "index table" and "mastertable" - what is its description and which values does it contain? What does it mean that you want to "dynamically update columns"? What do you call "dynamically"?

Comment: I have edited it..Can anyone help me?? Dynamically i mean the column can increase or decrease...